# Entity Framework Core transactions with parameters

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

This is a simplistic example but shows the error I am running into. I am trying to run in a transaction two commands which both have parameters.

Example

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
    using (IDbContextTransaction t = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
    { 
        using (var cmd = (IDbCommand) new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [#sessionlist] (Id bigint);" +
                "Insert into #sessionlist " +
                "select BlogId from blogs " +
                "where rating >= 10";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            var p = cmd.CreateParameter();
            p.ParameterName = "rating";
            p.Value = 10;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

            cmd.Connection = db.Database.GetDbConnection();
            cmd.Transaction = t.GetDbTransaction();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        using (var cmd = (IDbCommand) new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "update blogs set rating = @rating where BlogId in (select * from #sessionList)";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            var p = cmd.CreateParameter();
            p.ParameterName = "rating";
            p.Value = 10;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

            cmd.Connection = db.Database.GetDbConnection();
            cmd.Transaction = t.GetDbTransaction();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        t.Commit();
    }
}
```

Running this command fails with Invalid object name #sessionlist as it doesn't seem to run in the same transaction. If in the first cmd is modified so NO parameters are added, and instead the parameter is hardcoded. It executes ok.

How can I run multiple commands in a single transaction, both of which have their own parameters?

The production code is more complex and does require both commands be separate, as it creates a heavy temp table that is referenced in the second command.

Comment: You can not avoid using temp table? `update blogs set rating = @rating where BlogId in (select BlogId from blogs where rating >= 10)` you can't use update query like this?

Comment: No, we use something like this to do bulk batched deletes creating the Temp table is very heavy so we need it run only once and be usable during the batch delete.

Comment: The simplified logic of your code is, you are updating rating column value to 10 for all the blogs which has rating >=10. So you update query should be as simple as `UPDATE blogs set rating=10 WHERE rating >=10`. With this you don't need temp table or subquery. One simple update statement would do the job

Comment: Or you can have this entire thing written in stored procedure and execute stored proc from EF.